# Clearing MIDI output buffer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, midi, web-midi

Using the Web MIDI API, I can send some messages:

```
// Note on
output.send([0x90, 0x20, 0x50]);
```

I can also schedule some messages to be well-timed and sent in the future:

```
// Note off, 1 second later
output.send([0x80, 0x20, 0x40], performance.now() + 1000);
```

Now, suppose I've scheduled many messages to be sent in the future over several seconds, and now I want to cancel the sending of those messages.  [According to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmidi/#widl-MIDIOutput-clear-void), I should be able to call `clear` on the output:

```
output.clear();
```

However, this is undefined on Chrome (at least as of v79).

> Uncaught TypeError: output.clear is not a function

I assume this part just isn't implemented yet.  Is that the case?  And if so, is there some alternative I can use today?

Comment: How did you initialize the `output` variable? Would be helpful if you can post the relevant code too. You should also specify what version of Chrome you are testing against.

Comment: @Asesh `output` is just a `MIDIOutput`.  It's obtained by doing something like `const midi = await navigator.requestMIDIAccess()`, and then `midi.outputs.values().next().value`.  I'm not doing anything special, nor using any library.  It's the Web MIDI API, straight up.  Chrome v79.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471798&q=Midioutput%20clear&can=2

Comment: @Kaiido That's the one!  Thanks for finding it.  :-)  Could you please post that as an answer?  I'll kick the bounty over to you in a few days... I'll leave the question open for now, in case anyone knows of a viable workaround.

Comment: Posted a CW, please don't give the bounty to this answer, it only answers the small half of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed not yet available. 
You can follow [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471798&q=Midioutput%20clear&can=2) to get updated of any advancements.

Note that Firefox has a flag to allow the Web Midi API, might worth a try to see if they do handle it.

Comment: Thanks!!  Did not know about the Web MIDI flag in Firefox.

Comment: Update: Web MIDI in Firefox doesn't work at all.  :-(  The flag may enable it some day, but it's seemingly just mocked out for now.  Worse yet, it might get pulled.  There is a lot of incorrect information on the issue tracker about it and security concerns.